# Merge 2 JSON(Object Array) Data Restructuring

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, json, object

Can anyone help us, we have been on this for ages.
Basically, we want to merge 2 JSON responses dynamically by using **JSON Data 2( prodsub_id)** data with **JSON Data 1(id)**. Please see below sample JSON data.

### **JSON Data 1**

[
{
"enabled": 1,
"id": 1,
"parent_screen": "Products",
"category_title": "Regular Savings Account",
"category_desc": "Regular Savings Account",
"category_imgpath": "wdbwebsite/Products/RegSavings/Products-Regular_Savings_Account-Products-Regular_Savings_Account-Products-Regular_Savings_Account-Products-Regular_Savings_Account-Products-Regular_Savings_Account-ggggg.jpg",
"category_imgpath_filename": "Products-Regular_Savings_Account-Products-Regular_Savings_Account-Products-Regular_Savings_Account-Products-Regular_Savings_Account-Products-Regular_Savings_Account-ggggg.jpg",
"features": "Low maintaining balance\nInterest credited\nTransact conveniently at any WealthBank branch even on weekends with no Interbranch Service Fee",
"requirement": "wdbwebsite/Products/RegSavings/Products-Regular_Savings_Account-Requirement-Products-Regular_Savings_Account-Requirement-dtr0215.pdf",
"requirement_filename": "Products-Regular_Savings_Account-Requirement-Products-Regular_Savings_Account-Requirement-dtr0215.pdf",
"contactus_desc": null,
"retVal": 1,
"errmsg": "Data found"
},
{
"enabled": null,
"id": 11,
"parent_screen": "Products",
"category_title": "Special Savings Account",
"category_desc": "Special Savings Account",
"category_imgpath": "wdbwebsite/Products/SpecialSavings/Products-Special_Savings_Account-img-2.jpg",
"category_imgpath_filename": "Products-Special_Savings_Account-img-2.jpg",
"features": "Interest shall be credited upon maturity of the placement/term\nOption to roll-over the placement or top-up",
"requirement": "wdbwebsite/Products/SpecialSavings/Products-Special_Savings_Account-Requirement-Products-Regular_Savings_Account-Requirement-dtr0215.pdf",
"requirement_filename": "Products-Special_Savings_Account-Requirement-Products-Regular_Savings_Account-Requirement-dtr0215.pdf",
"contactus_desc": null,
"retVal": 1,
"errmsg": "Data found"
}
]

### **JSON DATA 2**

[
{
prodsub_id: 11,
parent_screen: 'Products',
narra_title: 'Nara title',
narra_content: 'nara content',
offer: 'offer1'
},
{
prodsub_id: 11,
parent_screen: 'Products',
narra_title: 'Nara title',
narra_content: 'nara content',
offer: 'offer2'
},
{
prodsub_id: 11,
parent_screen: 'Products',
narra_title: 'Nara title',
narra_content: 'nara content',
offer: null
},
{
prodsub_id: 10,
parent_screen: 'Products',
narra_title: 'Nara title',
narra_content: 'nara content',
offer: null
}
]

So to simplify it all.
We need to have this output.

### **JSON FINAL OUTPUT**

### {
"parent_screen": "Products",
"category_imgpath": "",
"narrative": [
{
"title": "qwe",
"content": "qwe"
},
{
"title": "w",
"content": "qwer"
},
{
"title": "qwer",
"content": "asdf"
}
],
"category_title": "Regular Savings Account",
"category_desc": "qwer",
"offer": [
"qwer",
"wqer",
"qwerwe"
],
"requirement": "",
"req_img": "",
"link": "regularsavingsaccount",
"features": "asdf",
"enabled": 1,
"id": 11,
"img": ""
}

Since the 2nd JSON data has a **prodsub_id** that is existing in the 1st JSON data **(id)**,
We would like to insert some 2nd JSON data into the 1st JSON data, as shown in **JSON FINAL OUTPUT**.
Sorry for my bad English, any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: what goes wrong?

Comment: too much bold, no formatting, no code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To achieve the **JSON FINAL OUTPUT**,

I did it like so, using array.map & array filter. Please see below.

```
var n_title,n_content;
var tempdata=[];

json1.map((item,index)=>{
    n_title=json2.filter((obj) => obj.prodsub_id==item.id).map(l =>l.narra_title)
    n_content=json2.filter((obj) => obj.prodsub_id==item.id).map(l => l.narra_content)
   
    n_title.map((itemss,i)=>{
     var data=[]
     data[i]={title:itemss,content:n_content[i]}
     tempdata.push(data[i]);
    })

    json1[index].narrative=tempdata;
    tempdata=[]
})
```

**A brief step-by-step explanation:**

1. Mapping the json1 data and inside it, create a filter for json2(narra_title, narra_content).
2. Mapping the the created **narra_title** filter(n_title) and inside it pushes the **narra_content** filtered data on a temporary array holder(tempdata);
3. Assigning the new data ( **tempdata** ) inside the mapped array (json1)

   like this : **json1[index].narrative=tempdata;**

   and lastly,setting tempdata back to **tempdata=[]** or **empty array**

Comment: My bad if the question I asked was not indented and untidy.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way I can think to do this (which may not be the best), would be to loop over the items in JSON 1 and then do a filter on JSON 2 to return any items with prodsub_id equal to the id of the current item from JSON 1 and then just add whatever fields you need from the matching item in JSON 2 (if one exists) to the current item from JSON 1.

Something like:

```js
json1.forEach(item => {
  const matched = json2.filter(i => i.prodsub_id == item.id);
  if(matched.length){
    // add stuff from matched to item
  }
});
```

Edit: If there is more than 1 match (`matched` will always be an array), you'll need to add logic inside the `if` to loop over each item that was matched and add whatever you need to `item`.

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter for info about the filter function.